# Gradient fading text on scroll on top of background

Tags: javascript, html, css, linear-gradients

Been looking for a way to fade a scroll in top and bottom.
I know the way where you use 2 png in top and bottom, problem is that only seems to be usefull when scroll in on a solid color page.
But i want it to happen on page where the there is a background image..

Any ideas? if its even possible?
JS, HTML5, CSS?

Here is a picture to describe the effect:

[image: gradient text scroll]

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you're looking for.

[image]

#### DEMO

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x2K4H/)

#### HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna.</p>
    <div class="fader"></div>
</div>​
```

#### CSS

```
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-c-640-480-3.jpg);
    font-family: Helvetica, 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

.wrap p {
    color: white;
}

.fader {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 30%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 70%, rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 30%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 70%, rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 30%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 70%, rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 100%);
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Edit: Added `pointer-events: none` to CSS to allow normal text selection.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I tried and seems to work:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        div.bg 
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            z-index: 0;
            width: 800px;
            height: 600px;
            background: url([your_background_image]);
        }

        div.txt 
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 50px;
            z-index: 2;
            width: 700px;
            height: 600px;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 30px;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        div.fader_in
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            z-index: 4;
            width: 800px;
            height: 100px;
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#FFFFFF'); /* for IE */
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#000000), to(#FFFFFF)); /* for webkit browsers */
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #000000,  #FFFFFF); /* for firefox 3.6+ */ 
            opacity: .5;
            -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
        }

        div.between
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 100px;
            left: 0px;
            z-index: 4;
            width: 800px;
            height: 400px;
            background: #FFFFFF;
            opacity: .5;
            -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
        }

        div.fader_out
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 500px;
            left: 0px;
            z-index: 4;
            width: 800px;
            height: 100px;
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#000000'); /* for IE */
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FFFFFF), to(#000000)); /* for webkit browsers */
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #FFFFFF,  #000000); /* for firefox 3.6+ */ 
            opacity: .5;
            -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="bg">
    </div>
    <div class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
    <div class="fader_in"></div>
    <div class="between"></div>
    <div class="fader_out"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a transparent grey-gradient image that matches your bg's color on top and bottom:
http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/fade_scroll.html

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question... Annoyingly it isn't possible to do it in a nice way that wont cause usability problems - i.e. like applying an opacity mask to the actual text layer. However you could achieve it with some heavy JavaScript/Canvas or you could use this mad method *(this will only work if you can have your background image having it's `background-attachment` set to `fixed`)*:

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">

  body {
    background: url(http://maxcdn.crazyleafdesign.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/cool-wallpapers-for-designers-29.jpg) fixed;
  }

  #scrollable {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 50px;
  }

  #scrollable .viewport {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  #scrollable .text {
    color: #fff;
  }

  #scrollable .text p {
    margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-bottom: 20px;
  }

  #scrollable .top {
    position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; height: 40px;
  }

  #scrollable .bot {
    position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; height: 40px;
  }

  #scrollable .top div, #scrollable .bot div {
    position: relative;
    background: url(http://maxcdn.crazyleafdesign.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/cool-wallpapers-for-designers-29.jpg) fixed;
    height: 2px;
    border: 0;
  }

  #scrollable .l01 { opacity: 1; }
  #scrollable .l02 { opacity: 0.95; }
  #scrollable .l03 { opacity: 0.9; }
  #scrollable .l04 { opacity: 0.85; }
  #scrollable .l05 { opacity: 0.8; }
  #scrollable .l06 { opacity: 0.75; }
  #scrollable .l07 { opacity: 0.7; }
  #scrollable .l08 { opacity: 0.65; }
  #scrollable .l09 { opacity: 0.6; }
  #scrollable .l10 { opacity: 0.55; }
  #scrollable .l11 { opacity: 0.5; }
  #scrollable .l12 { opacity: 0.45; }
  #scrollable .l13 { opacity: 0.4; }
  #scrollable .l14 { opacity: 0.35; }
  #scrollable .l15 { opacity: 0.3; }
  #scrollable .l16 { opacity: 0.25; }
  #scrollable .l17 { opacity: 0.2; }
  #scrollable .l18 { opacity: 0.15; }
  #scrollable .l19 { opacity: 0.1; }
  #scrollable .l20 { opacity: 0.05; }

</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="scrollable">
    <div class="viewport">
      <div class="text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et blandit ligula. Vestibulum sodales porttitor sollicitudin. Etiam turpis purus, tincidunt rhoncus interdum ut, mollis vitae mi. Nulla a mauris et orci scelerisque egestas a nec metus. Cras a massa id quam vehicula sodales. Etiam aliquam justo eu ligula volutpat blandit. Sed sagittis, arcu ut pulvinar blandit, purus mauris euismod felis, eget rutrum nunc arcu vitae augue. Cras magna quam, consectetur at lobortis quis, interdum eget tortor.</p>
        <p>Pellentesque tincidunt molestie urna, ut lacinia justo cursus a. Nunc mauris sem, dignissim id mollis vel, adipiscing nec purus. Fusce feugiat sem et neque cursus pretium. Curabitur tellus nunc, blandit sit amet aliquam tempus, scelerisque eu nulla. Vestibulum imperdiet nunc nec purus dignissim vitae suscipit orci pharetra. Mauris sit amet ante sit amet odio ultricies interdum auctor sit amet nibh. Integer ut sem leo, at vulputate felis. Mauris sit amet neque tortor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
        <p>Mauris lectus leo, luctus non malesuada vitae, facilisis vitae est. Maecenas sed neque lorem, vitae dignissim ante. Cras non lectus sed orci ornare ultricies at ac lectus. Donec quis quam mi, id ornare mauris. Praesent aliquet turpis hendrerit dui fringilla ullamcorper. Morbi facilisis urna non dui bibendum non semper neque dignissim. Vestibulum non pretium justo. Phasellus magna velit, commodo ut facilisis et, hendrerit vitae sem. Curabitur commodo eros a dolor sagittis egestas. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="top">
      <div class="l01"></div><div class="l02"></div><div class="l03"></div>
      <div class="l04"></div><div class="l05"></div><div class="l06"></div>
      <div class="l07"></div><div class="l08"></div><div class="l09"></div>
      <div class="l10"></div><div class="l11"></div><div class="l12"></div>
      <div class="l13"></div><div class="l14"></div><div class="l15"></div>
      <div class="l16"></div><div class="l17"></div><div class="l18"></div>
      <div class="l19"></div><div class="l20"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bot">
      <div class="l20"></div><div class="l19"></div><div class="l18"></div>
      <div class="l17"></div><div class="l16"></div><div class="l15"></div>
      <div class="l14"></div><div class="l13"></div><div class="l12"></div>
      <div class="l11"></div><div class="l10"></div><div class="l09"></div>
      <div class="l08"></div><div class="l07"></div><div class="l06"></div>
      <div class="l05"></div><div class="l04"></div><div class="l03"></div>
      <div class="l02"></div><div class="l01"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't recomend using any of these methods posted so far however (including mine), as they all interfere with text selection and the scrollbar due to the floating layers above the text. This can cause all manner of usability problems and basically just annoy your user... which isn't the aim of most websites ;)

Comment: ps. This has only been tested in the top modern browsers (FF, Chrome, Safari, Opera).. I'm pretty certain it will work for IE9/IE8... IE7 is anyones guess (you could increase support by including the browser prefixed opacity declarations -moz-opacity, -ms-opacity...). If you want IE6 support (please don't) you could also include Microsoft's Opacity filter, but that's only if you want hideous css and to perpetuate a browser that should be long long gone :)